# SQL logic for replace all old product values with new product ones

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need to build logic for replacing all old product names with new product names according to their related previous versions.
Here is the data and table look like. I have three columns named product_name, Intro_date, and previous_product_name.

**Current Table:**

```
product_name | Intro_date | previous_product_name
-------------------------------------------------

PRO01              6/1/2016 
PRO02              6/15/2016    
PRO03              6/15/2016    PRO02
PRO04              6/15/2016    PRO01
PRO05              8/1/2016
PRO06              9/1/2016     PRO04
PRO07              9/1/2016     PRO05
PRO08              10/15/2016   PRO06
PRO09              10/15/2016   PRO07
```

Now I want to create new column name “product_name_mapping” and the data values need to be populate like below output.

Example: if you look at PRO09’s previous product name is PRO07. And like same PRO07’s previous product name is PRO05… etc.

mapping is like this: PRO05 > PRO07 > PRO09

Now I want to replace all previous product name values PRO05, PRO07 with new product name value which is PRO09.

Same like for PRO08: PRO01 > PRO04 > PRO06 > PRO08

I want replace all previous product names (PRO01 > PRO04 > PRO06) with PRO08.

So here is what I am looking for final result.

**Result Table:**

```
product_name | Intro_date | previous_product_name | product_name_mapping
------------------------------------------------------------------------

*PRO01             6/1/2016                              PRO08
PRO02              6/15/2016                             PRO03
PRO03              6/15/2016    PRO02                    PRO03
PRO04              6/15/2016    PRO01                    PRO08
PRO05              8/1/2016                              PRO09
PRO06              9/1/2016     PRO04                    PRO08
PRO07              9/1/2016     PRO05                    PRO09
PRO08              10/15/2016   PRO06                    PRO08
PRO09              10/15/2016   PRO07                    PRO09
```

I have tried build logic and but no luck. I need to build this SQL in AWS Redshift database.
Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: What is the SQL you have built?

Comment: I built SQL for AWS Redshift

Comment: What I meant was if you already have a SQL of some sort we can help you to build on top of it or point out the problem with it

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a function with a while to loop through and get the current item. Then you could use the function in your query. I use SQL Server but perhaps you can convert this to AWS Redshift.

Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [guest].[get_mapping]( @product_name AS Varchar(256) )
RETURNS Varchar(256)
AS BEGIN 
    while (@@rowcount > 0)
    BEGIN
        select @product_name = product_name from <YourTable> where previous_product_name = @product_name;
    END
    RETURN @product_name; 
END
```

Select statement:

```
select *, get_mapping(product_name) as product_name_mapping from <yourtable>
```

Comment: This would not work in Redshift. Functions in Redshift can not access data

Comment: Thank you Nail, I am not sure is it possible to write SQL function in AWS redshift. But I will take a look into this.

Comment: You can create a function in Redshift but can not use most of the SQL like accessing data within the function

Comment: I'm not sure how you could do it with out a function. Either way it's not going to be very efficient for a large dataset.

Comment: You might be able to use Recursive? http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-recursive-query/